# How to show drupal menu in drop down?

Tags: 6, theming, routes, navigation

I am trying this code

```
   echo "<select>" .$main_nav = menu_tree('secondary-links');

            print"<option>"     .    $main_nav   . " </option></select>";<br>
```

but it display all menu at ones

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're building a so-called "jump menu", is that correct?

It's not considered good practice to code a menu into a template like you're doing in your example. Try to build the functionality of your site with modules (existing ones, or custom) and use the theme (template.php, CSS files, template files) for appearance only.

If you need a jump menu, have a look at the [Jump](http://drupal.org/project/jump) module. It provides a block for every top-level menu and every vocabulary, so it could get you exactly what you need without writing one line of code.

Comment: About splitting the code: could you point us to some references (articles, existing themes etc.) where it's done well? I'm interested.

Comment: For instance, see how [menu_tree_output()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/6) builds a list of menu items and then calls `theme('menu_item_link', ...)`, `theme('menu_item', ...)` and `theme('menu_tree', ...)` to generate the html. See also [Using the theme layer](http://drupal.org/node/165706) in the module developers guide.